# MySQL Connector/C++ libraries not found Linking

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, mysql-connector, connector

I have been trying to use the MySQL connector with c++ in visual studio, but this didn't work out for me so far.

I have been following https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html instructions twice, however visual studio still can't find the requiered header files.

I have tried linking mysqlcppconn-static.lib and mysqlcppconn.lib in the project properties.

The following code is used in the example code for the MySQL Connector.

```
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
```

[image]

Comment: You mention "header files', but header files are not used at all in the link phase.  Please post the exact error message(s) you're getting.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie added the errors now

Comment: Have you added header files' root dir to compiler include path? The error says that it cannot find the header file.

Comment: @i486 Welli have been following the instruction and it stated to link the folder with the libraries, later I found all these files on Github and included them in quotation marks like normally I would do and it worked. however I don't think it's meant to be added like that since you have to copy 20 files each time you work with it. I expected the use of the .lib or .dll

Comment: @user3002135 There are 2 things: header file(s) and library (.lib) file(s). The errors here are at compile time (cannot open/find headers). It is not necessary to copy headers - only add its location to include path.